# Changing rows at random in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe - and one column has airline names (or company names).
I want to generate a 'messy' data set by changing a small subset of the names (which are only in one column) to names that are similar but not the same. 
So United Airlines would become UNITED AIRLINES say.
The following is an example of my data set

```
Description
0   United Airlines
1   Pinnacle Airlines Inc.
2   Ryanair
3   British Airways
```

Is there anyway to randomly apply changes of stings by row to a Pandas data frame.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.random.choice` to return a random selection of your index, it takes a 1-D array and returns a random selection of the size you pass:

```
In [177]:

rand_indices = np.random.choice(df.index, 2)
rand_indices.sort()
rand_indices
Out[177]:
array([1, 2], dtype=int64)
In [178]:

df.loc[rand_indices]
Out[178]:
              Description  a
1  Pinnacle Airlines Inc.  1
2                 Ryanair  2
In [179]:

def scramble_text(df, index, col):
    df.loc[index, col] = df[col].str.upper()

scramble_text(df, rand_indices, 'Description')
df
Out[179]:
              Description  a
0         United Airlines  0
1  PINNACLE AIRLINES INC.  1
2                 RYANAIR  2
3         British Airways  3
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was after. I need to learn the df.loc function better :)